# How can i subdivide a cylinder so that i looks smooth?

Tags: modeling

Modelling beginner question:

I know i can choose number of vertices of a cylinder before hand. But how can i subdivide a cylinder which is already made?

i have this edgy thing here, but i want a smoooooooooth circle:

[image]

the result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Subdivision surface? if that's not what you mean, the question is really not very clear

Comment: Just try it - it will „kill“ the whole cylinder  I want a perfect circle for the cylinder top/bottom

Comment: Whe you are modelling with subdivision modifier, you could use "support edges" or bevel the border.

Comment: Here are two examples https://imgur.com/a/z8ctpwV

Comment: i updated my question, maybe it was not clear. I don't wanna bevel, i want to have a perfectly round cylinder

Comment: It can't be perfectly round, it will appear round to a certain point if you zoom in. Also don't forget to shade smooth so that the shading appears smooth

Comment: ok i can make it by adding edge loops...then it works

Comment: @moonboots: that's ok, i am fine with that. But i don't wanna see edges from far ;)

Comment: A loop cut are the option there. But as @moonboots say "its going to be round to a certain point" https://imgur.com/a/1IQ3IRN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdivision surface modifier and then shift + E to make the edges sharp and keep the cylinder shape.

Comment: if i do that, the circle won't get round...it keeps edgy....or i am doing something wrong

Comment: the roundness will depend on the subdivision value you'll choose in the modifier

Comment: and this works without adding additional edge loops?

Comment: ok, got it, i made it wrong. Thx!